# parent with inline-css does not take the width of its content

Tags: html, css

I have a parent container with the following css:

```
.options {
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  color: black;
  display: inline-block !important;
  margin-top: 100px;
  left: 50%;
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

And its child has:

```
.optionContainer{
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
```

What I try to achieve is to align the children one next to the other and the parent to expand to their total width, the number of children is not fixed. This works with flexbox.

But I want to achieve it with inline-block because I have to support older browsers.

Comment: You mean inline-block by saying inline-box?

Comment: @AHBagheri yes, sorry, updating. Using inline-block on the child doesnt seem to solve the issue

Comment: As I corrected the answer, only remove float left and it should work.

Comment: @AHBagheri doesnt solve the issue, see update

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fxm3kpj7/

Comment: @AHBagheri in this small example works, but with my full parent tree doesnt. Here a fiddle that reproduces the issue http://jsfiddle.net/2hoz47se/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the child float left. It should have float:none. Besides, display of the child should be:inline-block.

https://jsfiddle.net/fxm3kpj7/

```
.optionContainer{
    display: inline-block;
 }
```

Comment: Here is the full dom tree where I have the problem, http://jsfiddle.net/2hoz47se/

Answer (score 0):

I would try to give the parent `display: block`, a defined `min-width`, fixed `height` and `overflow-x: visible`.